How do i solve this error Object optimistic locking failure exception in java
I am having object optimisitic locking failure exception, in my model i have post, users, comment , message, email, and status. In the post service i implemented the logic to creatpost, edit, delete etc and in the user service i called the post service and find the post by it's id, i check for the user by it's id and then create a list of post and add the post and return the post response when i run my test it throw this exception.
I tried to put @transaction to manage all transaction and i also added @version to the post model but it's still did'nt work
This is the test
@Test
public void testThatUsersCanUploadPost() throws UserAlreadyExistException, UserNotFoundException, PostNotFoundException {
    buildUsersRegistrationRequest();
    RegisterUsersResponse registerUserResponse = userService.register(buildUsersRegistrationRequest());
    assertNotNull(registerUserResponse);
    CreatePostRequest createPostRequest = new CreatePostRequest();
    createPostRequest.setReferencePostId(1L);
    createPostRequest.setUserId(1L);
    createPostRequest.setContent("Software engineering no be garri!!");
    createPostRequest.setImageUrl("http://localhost");
    createPostRequest.setPostCreatedAt(now());
    CreatePostResponse response = postService.createPost(createPostRequest);
    assertEquals("Post created successfully", response.getMessage());
    CreatePostResponse userCreatedPostResponse = userService.createContent(createPostRequest);
    assertEquals("Post created successfully", userCreatedPostResponse.getMessage());
    assertNotNull(userCreatedPostResponse);
    log.info("userCreatedPostResponse: {}", userCreatedPostResponse);
    log.info("response: {}", response);
}





Below is the implementation:
  @Override
    public CreatePostResponse createContent(CreatePostRequest createPostRequest) throws UserNotFoundException, PostNotFoundException {
       CreatePostResponse createPostResponse = postService.createPost(createPostRequest);
      Post post = postService.getPostsById(createPostRequest.getReferencePostId());
       Users user = userRepository.findById(createPostRequest.getUserId())
               .orElseThrow(()-> new UserNotFoundException(String.format("User %s not found", createPostRequest)));
       List<Post> listOfPost = user.getPosts();
       listOfPost.add(post);
       userRepository.save(user);
       createPostResponse.setMessage("Content created successfully");
        return createPostResponse;
    }

Below is the stack trace:
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.fontmedia.africa.nija.fontmedia.data.model.Post#1]

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:325)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:560)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:165)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy116.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.fontmedia.africa.nija.fontmedia.service.implimentation.PostServiceImpl.createPost(PostServiceImpl.java:32)
    at com.fontmedia.africa.nija.fontmedia.service.interfaces.UserServiceTest.testThatUsersCanUploadPost(UserServiceTest.java:66)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.fontmedia.africa.nija.fontmedia.data.model.Post#1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.merge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.doMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:320)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy112.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:626)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:515)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:284)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:380)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138)
    ... 10 more

2024-12-01T12:45:32.648+01:00  INFO 12584 --- [fontmedia] [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalCo

